# Is God,if there is any, is He moving or standing still,in the space that surrounds Him?

Tags: theology

Everything in this universe moves, the earth along with the solar system,our milky way, everything. Now, when we say that an object is standing still, it's standing still in respect to the observer, but actually it's moving along with the universe. 
So God, to Him, is the whole universe moving(imagining that He's at watching it from a distance)? And if God sees the universe standstill, how can we be sure that He is not moving?

Comment: "Everything" in this context means every physical object; if God is not "physical", then he has no spce that surround him.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE. Without a common understanding of the concept 'God', this is unanswerable. Please [edit] your question to provide more context, and it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

History suggests this question is really a '[category error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake)' in which an unanswerable question arises from asking about the value of a property that the thing being asked about cannot have.

It is not wise to pointlessly apply human concepts to God.  There are long traditions of not attributing to God whatever can be avoided.  You can expect trouble applying limiting notions to what is by definition unlimited.  And we are not good at realizing that most of our notions are limiting.

Things like motion are especially ill-fitting to any sort of defined perfection.  They lead us directly into paradoxes.  Looking at them too closely yields, e.g. Zeno's paradox.  Why would any concept with internal flaws of its own be an attribute of any kind of perfect being?

Particularly, from a Kantian point of view, space and time do not accord perfectly with logic.  They produce 'antinomies' like the impossibility of time either beginning or not beginning.  So they are not absolute and do not apply to all things.  Kant decides ultimately that those concepts, and therefore the concept of movement, which is just the combination of the two, are limiting principles that humans generate to organize their own perception.  Movement is not a universal concept, and it does not apply to non-animal sorts of intelligence like God.

Going back even further, Augustine had already suggested that God is outside time on more basic theological grounds.  If God is always the same, he must already remember the future, for discovering it would alter him.  Therefore God does not experience time.  If he does not experience time, how would we describe him as moving or standing still?  We might do so from our own perspective, but He could not agree.  Why argue with God?

So there are at least three traditional reasons to insist this question has no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think God is part of the Universe at all? Can you imagine the Universe in more than 3 dimensions? If you have a sheet of paper and you envelop it with other sheet of paper are they the same thing? Or is the new sheet of paper touching the old in every point of it?

Now, can you imagine God like this second sheet of paper touching every point of the Universe but yet not being part of any of it? He or she (not sure about the gender of God) may be everywhere but at the same time in a dimension different from ours. This is why some people call it higher dimension. It is part of the Universe but we can not see it because it is not part of our 3 dimensions we are living in. Then what is the problem for God to be everywhere and the same time nowhere, to be standstill and be moving at the same time because it isn't he or she who is moving but our entire Universe.

Can you understand my answer?

Comment: I got your point.